# UITableView Not Displaying Latest Data When Using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, ios7, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView on it.  I have set the delegate and datasource for the UITableView to be the UIViewController in IB and also in the viewDidLoad.  I have implemented all the delegate methods as per the apple documentation for UITableView and NSFetchedResultsController and I am seeing the core data information being loaded into the UITableView when the app launches.

```
...
[NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Stuff"];

self.tableview.delegate = self;
self.tableview.dataSource = self;
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
self.tableview.allowsSelection = NO;
self.sNavBar.delegate = self;
...
```

There is also a modal view that appears when a UIButton is tapped.  When I add a new item using the modal view and then dismiss the modal view the UITableView on the parent UIViewController does not refresh with the latest data.

If I kill the app and restart it then item I added gets loaded into the UITableView.  So I can see that the NSFetchedResultsController is loading my data but doesn't load the newly added data while the app is running.

I have been trying for hours to get this hooked up properly but I cannot see the problem.  I have also tried deleting the fetchedresultscontroller cache.

I added a method to perform the fetch for the fetchedresultscontroller and it gets called when the modal is dismissed and also when the pulldown refresh happens on UITableView.

```
- (void)loadRecordsFromCoreData {

    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    // Update to handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
}
```

When the modal view is dismissed I call the viewWillAppear method which should reload the table view but I think there is a race condition here where new item is not added yet when the modal view disappears.  The above loadRecordsFromCoreData does get called at this point.  So to test that I added a refresh pulldown to the UITableView but this also does not pull in the newly added item.

UPDATE 1:

When I save the new item on the modal view in code below I then raise a notification:

```
- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {

 if (![self.txtEvent.text isEqualToString:@""]) {


     [self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error = nil;
        BOOL saved = [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
        if (!saved) {
            // do some real error handling
            NSLog(@"Could not save due to %@", error);
        }
        [[MVCoreDataController sharedInstance] saveMasterContext];
    }];


     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refresh" object:nil];
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
         [delegate modalWasDismissed:self];
     }];       

 }
 else
 {

     UIAlertView *cannotSaveAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uh oh..." message:@"Some Problem." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [cannotSaveAlert show];

 }
}
```

This "refresh" selector then calls viewWillAppear on the parent view controller which calls loadRecordsFromCoreData and [self.tableview reloadData] but nothing new appears in the table.

In viewWillAppear on the parent view controller I have the following code:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:YES];
[self loadRecordsFromCoreData];
[self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say "I call the viewWillAppear method", what do you mean exactly?  Are you actually trying to invoke this method by calling it manually?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't get called otherwise when the modal view is dismissed.

Comment: When I changed "self.managedObjectContext" in my parent view controller to "managedObjectContext" the table started to update.  But I do not know why because it was able to get the data into the table from the managedObjectContext in the first place just wasn't refreshing it.

Comment: Have you had luck with any of the answers provided?

Comment: Not yet.  I had the [self.tablevview reloadData]; code in my code already so doing that was, although helpful, not the answer.  When I changed self.managedObjectContext to just managedObjectContext the code I already had started to work but I do not know why.

Answer (score 2):

```
[self.tableview reloadData];
```

Call the `reloadData` method on a `tableView` any time you want it to, well, reload its data.

You could even pass the `tableView` to the modal view you're displaying so that the table view could be refreshed from the modal view in its `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: I am calling [self.tableview reloadData] but the newly added item does not appear.

Comment: Where are you calling this method?

Comment: I raise a notification when the modal is dismissed which calls a method back on the parent view controller.  This method calls viewWillAppear which I will update the code onto the original question above.

Comment: Are you calling explicitly `[self.tableView reloadData]` in view will appear?

Comment: Yes. Updating the viewWillAppear code to the original question.